# How to write RegEx in Shell Script?

Tags: linux

How to write RegEx in Shell Script to fail the script with exit code 1 if any of the input parameters contain possible shell injection commands. One or two examples are sufficient. Plz help.

Here is the code snippet:

```
invalid_format="^.*[;&|].*$"

invalid_format2="rmdir"

if [ "$LOCAL_DIR" =~ "$invalid_format" -o "$LOCAL_DIR" =~ "$invalid_format2" ]; 
then

echo "Error! LOCAL_DIR cannot contain command chaining characters like ; && ||"

exit 1

fi
```

but, it fails with the error:

```
[: too many arguments
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! If you already haven't, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried until this point ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? grep might be a good place to start

Comment: Any particular shell or just any shell in general?

Comment: I mean the Linux Shell.

Comment: I know grep can search files. Not sure how to use it in if statement to match a particular pattern of input paramters.

Comment: For future references, you can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ . Simply pasting your code in it highlighted the syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` and pipe your string into `grep`, then check the return value.

```
#!/bin/bash
STRING_TO_CHECK="abc"
REGEX="b"

echo "$STRING_TO_CHECK" | grep -E "$REGEX"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
  # regex not found
else
  # regex found
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone.. here I got this get done.

```
invalid_format="(^.[;&|].$)|(\brmdir\b)|(\bls\b)|(rm\s-)|(\bping\b)"

if [[ $LOCAL_DIR =~ $invalid_format ]]; then

echo "Error! LOCAL_DIR cannot contain command chaining characters like ; && || or possible shell injection commands"

exit 1
```